# Haskell function works with char type but is not working with number type

Tags: haskell

I'm really new to Haskell and functional programming in general, and I can't figure out why I keep getting "Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a] (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)" errors.

I have this function for looking up value in dictionary by key:

```
lookup1 x [] = []
lookup1 x (h:t) = if x == fst h then snd h else lookup1 x t
```

and it is working fine with char type, for example, `lookup1 "b" [("a", "aa"), ("b", "bb"), ("c", "cc")]` returns "bb". But when I try the same with number type, for example `lookup1 2 [(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33)]` I get this:

```
* Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
* When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall a. Num [a] => [a]
```

Weird thing is that if I define the same function in `ghci` it works with both chars and numbers.

As I also need function for returning all values from dictionary where dictionary can contain duplicate keys, I tried this workaround:

```
    lookup_duplicates x [] = []
    lookup_duplicates x (h:t) = if x == fst h then (snd h):(lookup_duplicates x t) else lookup_duplicates x t 
    lookup1 x (h:t) = let (a:b) = lookup_duplicates x (h:t) in a
```

which takes first value from `lookup_duplicates` and it did work fine. But now I have this function that finds all values for given keys in dictionary:

```
    find_all_values [] (h:t) = []
    find_all_values (g:a) (h:t) = let found = (lookup1 g (h:t)) in (if found == [] then find_all_values a (h:t) else found:(find_all_values a (h:t)))
```

which also works very good with char types but with number types I get this:

```
* Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a1]
  (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
* When checking the inferred type
    it :: forall a1. (Num [a1], Eq a1) => [[a1]]
```

Can anyone please guide me to the right direction?

Comment: What types do you think these functions should be?

Comment: @AJFarmar I think that the type should depend on the type of given parameters

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but what should the type signature of  `find_all_values` be? Use type variables.

Comment: @AJFarmar But I wrote other functions in haskell, and they do work fine with both chars and numbers.

Comment: I didn't ask about other functions; I know that Haskell can use polymorphism too. What type would `find_all_values` be? If you try this, you may find out what the issue here is.

Comment: @AJFarmar It should be list, for example, `find_all_values ["a", "b"] [("a", "aa"), ("b", "bb"), ("c", "cc")]` should return `["aa", "bb"]` and `find_all_values [1, 2] [(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33)]` should return `[11, 22]`.

Comment: That's the type of `find_all_values ["a","b"] [("a", "aa"), ("b","bb)]`, not the type of `find_all_value`. What would the type of `find_all_values` be?

Comment: Look at the inferred type of `lookup1`; if it gets an empty list, it tries to return an empty list of some type. Otherwise, it might return an `Int` or a `Char`, or whatever type the second element of a tuple has. There is also the problem  that when you give it a bunch of values of type `Num a => a`, it can't seem to figure out which instance of `Eq` to use to do the comparisons.

Comment: @chepner And what would be a solution to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at

```
lookup1 x [] = []
lookup1 x (h:t) = if x == fst h then snd h else lookup1 x t
```

What's its type? The first equation says that we're taking two arguments, where the first is of unknown type, and the second is a list of unknown type, and we're returning another list of unknown type:

```
lookup1 :: _a -> [_b] -> [_c] -- Not fully solved
```

In the second equation, when you use `fst` and `snd` on the head of your second argument, you force that second argument to be a list of pairs

```
lookup1 :: _a -> [(_b, _d)] -> [_c]
```

and since your function can evaluate to `snd h`, we know that `_d` must be `[_c]`.

```
lookup1 :: _a -> [(_b, [_c])] -> [_c]
```

and since you check `(==)` between the first argument and `fst h`, we know that `_a ~ _b` and `Eq _a`

```
lookup1 :: Eq _a => _a -> [(_a, [_c])] -> [_c]
```

That's all the information we have, so we say we've totally solved this type and replace all the remaining variables with universally quantified types:

```
lookup1 :: Eq a => a -> [(a, [b])] -> [b]
```

and if you ask `:type lookup1` in GHCi it'll tell you the same. This is wrong, because you can only ever use this to look up *lists* of things, when you should be able to look up whatever you want! Specifically, this function will either look up the target list, or, if it can't find it, evaluate to `[]` instead. Also, you say it works fine for `Char`, and give the example

```
lookup1 "b" [("a", "aa"), ("b", "bb"), ("c", "cc")]
```

But that isn't `Char`! That's `[Char]` (aka `String`)! `String`s are zero or more characters enclosed in `""`; `Char`s are exactly one character enclosed in `''`.

Also, if you tried

```
lookup1 'b' [('a', "a")]
```

you'd get `""`, and that's not really a sensible output, because you don't know if `"b"` was found and just happened to point to `""`, or it wasn't there at all and we just defaulted.

When you try

```
lookup1 2 [(1, 11), (2, 22), (3, 33)]
```

each numeric literal starts with type `Num _a => _a` (Haskell numeric literals are polymorphic). The type of `lookup1` forces the second element of every pair to also be a list of something, so `11`, `22`, and `33` take on the type `Num [a] => [a]`, which is not allowed without the `FlexibleContexts` language extension (and is nonsense regardless).

The *correct* type for this is

```
lookup1 :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
lookup1 _ []     = _ -- Exercise for reader
lookup1 x (e:es) = _
```

Now, `lookupDuplicates` (camel case is the convention) should have the type

```
lookupDuplicates :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> [b]
```

which is true for what you wrote, but now `lookup1` is bad:

```
lookup1 x (h:t) = let (a:b) = lookupDuplicates x (h:t) in a
```

What happens if you give it an empty list? You will try to match it to `h:t`, which will fail. Worse, you only take the list apart to put it back again. It should just be

```
lookup1 x es = head $ lookupDuplicates x es
-- Read: First result of looking up x in es
```

Yet, this is still undesirable. If you don't find your entry anywhere, you throw a runtime error (which you cannot catch unless you're in the `IO` monad). You want to use another monad, probably `Maybe`, for this:

```
lookup1 :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
lookup1 x es = case lookupDuplicates x es of
                    []    -> _ -- Exercise for reader
                    (e:_) -> _
```

The `listsafe` library provides versions of list functions that work in `Maybe` instead of being partial, so if you had that installed you could say

```
import qualified Data.List.Safe as LS
lookup1 x es = LS.head $ lookupDuplicates x es
```

Now, onto `findAllValues`

```
findAllValues [] (h:t) = []
findAllValues (g:a) (h:t) = let found = (lookup1 g (h:t))
                            in if found == []
                                  then findAllValues a (h:t)
                                  else found:(findAllValues a (h:t))
```

You can write this much more clearly:

```
import Data.Maybe
findAllValues :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a, b)] -> [b]
findAllValues keys dict = catMaybes $ flip lookup1 dict <$> keys
-- Go over the list of keys with (flip lookup1 dict), then remove the Maybes
-- (flip lookup1 dict) is a function that takes a key and looks it up in dict
-- (<$>) is the infix version of fmap which is the general version of map
-- catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]
-- Nothings stop existing and the Just wrappings evaporate
```

If you used the

```
import qualified Data.List.Safe as LS
lookup1 x es = LS.head $ lookupDuplicates x es
```

version above, then the most general type of `lookup` is actually `(MonadThrow m, Eq a) => a -> [(a, b)] -> m b`, which means `findAllValues` simplifies to:

```
findAllValues keys dict = concat $ flip lookup1 dict <$> keys
```

because `MonadThrow []`. (A failed `lookup1` "magically" returns `Nothing` in some cases and `[]` in others and `Left (SomeException EmptyListException)` in yet others, all depending on type.)

Final note: always think of your type signatures first and write them down (at least for top level definitions). It really helps you get a handle on what you should do.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for brief explanation. Actually, now I do remember trying to write lookup1 function with` Maybe`s but I got really confused about `Just`s in results but now I see how to get rid of them. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you don't return a correct value from `lookup1` when an item isn't found. You can't just return an empty list, because you aren't necessarily returning a list in the other cases (it depends on the type of value found in the tuples). Instead, you need to return a value of some `Maybe` type:

```
lookup1 :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
lookup1 x [] = Nothing
lookup1 x ((k,v):t) | x == k = Just v
                    | otherwise = lookup1 x t
```

Alternatively, you *could* guarantee that list is returned, one containing zero or one values. This isn't ideal, though, since the type doesn't guarantee only an empty or singleton value is returned.

```
lookup1 :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> [b]
    lookup1 x [] = []
    lookup1 x ((k,v):t) | x == k = [v]
                        | otherwise = lookup1 x t
```

The reason your code worked for `lookup1 "b" [("a", "aa"), ("b", "bb"), ("c", "cc")]` is that you were using `String` values, and `String` is just an alias for `[Char]`; `[]` was a valid base case in that instance.

Comment: In the first `lookup1` you have, you should return `Just v` in the successful branch.

Comment: Huh, thought I remembered fixing that. Apparently I didn't.